# How to use ABUnknownPersonViewController with generated data entered intially?

Tags: ios, addressbook, addressbookui

This is very specific case. I believe someone had already solved this somewhere, but it's not easy for me to find it.

The situation:

1 ) an object will return `NSString` objects for name address1, address2, phone:

```
[anObject name];
[anObject address1];
[anObject address2];
[anObject name];
```

2 ) I would like to use these objects to prepare `ABUnknownPersonViewController` with initially entered values, so the user will not have to enter them before saving them in Address Book.

I have looked at iOS documents and searched through Google and StackOverflow, can't find the right answer for this simple situation.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer: It's nicely documented in iOS Developer Library:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Listings/Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475-Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

Here is a sample code I implemented to return a ABPersonRecordRef as an object. The error I had experienced was related to not retaining the ABPersonRecordRef object after returning it.

```
- (id)personRecordUsingModelObj:(id)modelObj {
    ABRecordRef aContact = ABPersonCreate();
    CFErrorRef anError = NULL;

    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [modelObj name]];
    ABRecordSetValue(aContact, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, name, &anError);  

    ABMultiValueRef phone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phone, [modelObj phone], kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);

    ABRecordSetValue(aContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phone, &anError);
    CFRelease(phone);

    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [modelObj addr1], [modelObj addr2]];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryAddress = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    [dictionaryAddress setObject:address forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
    [dictionaryAddress setObject:@"us" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey];

    ABMutableMultiValueRef address = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABDictionaryPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, dictionaryAddress, kABPersonAddressStreetKey, NULL);
    [dictionaryAddress release];

    ABRecordSetValue(aContact, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, &anError);
    CFRelease(address); 

    if (anError) {
        aContact = nil;
    }

    [(id)aContact autorelease];

    return (id)aContact;
}
```